# Get a part from URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I get the part before "?" of a URL with jQuery?

For example, I have following URL:
http://example/group/abc/?author=gfg&city=gfg

I want to get this:
http://example/group/abc/

---

If the URL is this:
http://example/group/abc/xyz?author=gfg&city=gfg

I want to get this URL:
http://example/group/abc/xyz

Comment: please show us what you have tried. google "jquery get substring", read and experiment.

Comment: Nothing in core jQuery is designed for URL parsing.

Comment: See over there on the right where it says **Related**? Have a look at a few of those

Comment: ManoDestra: Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No jQuery Necessary.
`window.location.href.split('?')[0]`

Comment: Esko: Thanks a lot. It is helpful answer.